# Qt OpenGL Window Example black screen and freezing when window is dragged, why?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, opengl

I followed this example: [OpenGL Window Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/openglwindow.html) using Qt 5 built for msvc2012. When I run the application, the window is black and when I attempt to resize or drag the window, the application freezes until I shift focus (alt-tap) from the application and back to it again. I can maximize, minimize and close the application with the standard windows decorations (while not frozen).